# Append new webhook to alertmanager config file using shell

Tags: text-processing, yaml

I am using alertmanager for notification purpose and by default `alertmanager` only has one webhook. As per my requirement one more webhook is required.

**Existing config**

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m

route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: {{ getsdcv "system" "group_wait" "10s"}}
  group_interval: {{ getsdcv "system" "group_interval" "10s"}}
  {{- $repeat_interval := getsdcv "system" "repeat_interval" "" }}
  {{- if not (eq $repeat_interval "") }}
  repeat_interval: {{ $repeat_interval }}
  {{- end }}
  receiver: 'web.hook'
receivers:
- name: 'web.hook'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'http://{{ getsdcv "system" "ip" "localhost"}}:{{ getsdcv "system" "port" "8005"}}/'

inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: 'critical'
    target_match:
      severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instance']
```

**After adding new Webhook**

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m

route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: {{ getsdcv "system" "group_wait" "10s"}}
  group_interval: {{ getsdcv "system" "group_interval" "10s"}}
  {{- $repeat_interval := getsdcv "system" "repeat_interval" "" }}
  {{- if not (eq $repeat_interval "") }}
  repeat_interval: {{ $repeat_interval }}
  {{- end }}
  receiver: 'web.hook'
  routes:
    - receiver: "web.hook"
      continue: true
    - receiver: "web.hook1"
      match:
        alertname: BusinessKpiDown
      continue: true
receivers:
- name: 'web.hook'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'http://{{ getsdcv "system" "ip" "localhost"}}:{{ getsdcv "system" "port" "8005"}}/'

- name: 'web.hook1'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'http://0.0.0.0:8010/hooks/my-webhook'

inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: 'critical'
    target_match:
      severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instance']
```

I tried doing it through shell script but failed

```
awk -v RS='^$' '{$0=gensub(/(receivers:\s+users:)(\s+)/,"\\1\\2- name: 'web.hook2'\\2",1)}1'
```

But unable to append new webhook.

Comment: Your updated YAML file is not well formed.  It is not a proper YAML file.

Comment: I do not have ownership of this content of yaml file. I am unable to identify the issue with format, need to handle that as well if possible.

Comment: It's obvious that there is some template engine that processes the file before it's turned into proper YAML. It would be easier to work with YAML than with this template document. It's unknown to me why you first had proper YAML in your question and then switched it out after getting two answers.

Comment: The previous yaml is output come from this yaml which contains variable. on line no 8

Answer (score 2):

Note:  This answer worked with a very different input document which looked like

```yaml
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m

route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 10s
  repeat_interval: 12h
  receiver: 'web.hook'
receivers:
- name: 'web.hook'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: ''
inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: 'critical'
    target_match:
      severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instance']
```

That document has now been modified in the question so that it's no longer a valid YAML file, so this answer can't unfortunately be used as is.  I'm leaving it here for the benefit of whoever might find it interesting.

---

It looks like you want to add the following entry to the `receivers` array:

```yaml
- name: web.hook2
  webhook_configs:
    - url: ''
```

... and then also

```yaml
- continue: true
```

to each `receivers` element's `webhook_configs` section.

We may do this with `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/:

```bsh
yq -y '
    .receivers += [{"name":"web.hook2","webhook_configs":[{"url":""}]}] | 
    .receivers |= map(.webhook_configs += [{"continue":true}])' file.yaml
```

This uses `yq`, which is a YAML-aware wrapper around the JSON parser `jq`, to add the wanted section to the `receivers` array, and then adds a extra key-value to the `webhook_configs` entries in the `receivers` array.

Would you want to pass the name of the new web hook, and its URL, on the command line, don't inject it as a string with a shell variable in the `yq` expression, but create a `yq` variable properly (allowing `yq` to safely encode the value if needed):

```bsh
myname='web.hook2'
myurl=''

yq -y --arg name "$myname" --arg url "$myurl" '
    .receivers += [{"name":$name,"webhook_configs":[{"url":$url}]}] | 
    .receivers |= map(.webhook_configs += [{"continue":true}])' file.yaml
```

`yq` also supports "in-place" editing using its `-i` or `--in-place` options.

The result given the example in the question:

```yaml
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
route:
  group_by:
    - alertname
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 10s
  repeat_interval: 12h
  receiver: web.hook
receivers:
  - name: web.hook
    webhook_configs:
      - url: ''
      - continue: true
  - name: web.hook2
    webhook_configs:
      - url: ''
      - continue: true
inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: critical
    target_match:
      severity: warning
    equal:
      - alertname
      - dev
      - instance
```

If you run with `-Y` in place of `-y`, you stop`yq` from sorting out your mixed markup:

```yaml
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 10s
  repeat_interval: 12h
  receiver: 'web.hook'
receivers:
  - name: 'web.hook'
    webhook_configs:
      - url: ''
      - continue: true
  - name: web.hook2
    webhook_configs:
      - url: ''
      - continue: true
inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: 'critical'
    target_match:
      severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instance']
```

You may also remove the indentation on the lists, like you have in your original document, by supplying the `--indentless-lists` option to `yq`.

---

Since `yq` is a wrapper around `jq`, the `yq` expression deals with a document that has been translated into JSON.  This document is then translated back to YAML by `yq`.  For reference, the following is the JSON-variant of your original document, which is modified by the `yq` expression:

```json
{
  "global": {
    "resolve_timeout": "5m"
  },
  "route": {
    "group_by": [
      "alertname"
    ],
    "group_wait": "10s",
    "group_interval": "10s",
    "repeat_interval": "12h",
    "receiver": "web.hook"
  },
  "receivers": [
    {
      "name": "web.hook",
      "webhook_configs": [
        {
          "url": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "inhibit_rules": [
    {
      "source_match": {
        "severity": "critical"
      },
      "target_match": {
        "severity": "warning"
      },
      "equal": [
        "alertname",
        "dev",
        "instance"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two popular `yq` projects, [the one](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) @Kusalananda
featured and [mikefarah's](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) `yq`. Here is how to do the same thing with the
second one (yq version 4.11.2):

```
yq e -P '
  .receivers += [{"name":"web.hook2", "webhook_configs": [{"url":""}]}] |
  .receivers[].webhook_configs += [{"continue":true}]
' infile.yaml
```

The `-P` switch pretty-prints the yaml. Output:

```yaml
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
route:
  group_by:
    - alertname
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 10s
  repeat_interval: 12h
  receiver: web.hook
receivers:
  - name: web.hook
    webhook_configs:
      - url: ""
      - continue: true
  - name: web.hook2
    webhook_configs:
      - url: ""
      - continue: true
inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: critical
    target_match:
      severity: warning
    equal:
      - alertname
      - dev
      - instance
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am encountering yaml validation error while using your command with my updated yaml, Please see updated yaml or can we ignore yaml validation look like we cannot do it through swe, awk or can we ?,

Comment: error: Error: yaml: line 8: could not find expected ':'                                              
Assumption: Original yaml cannot be edited once

Comment: @VineyDhiman: it isn't valid yaml

Comment: yes it's a system generated file. cannot make changes into it.

Comment: its YAML template from which actual YAML will be generated.